# Using TeX to split words into syllables

Tags: typography, hyphenation

I know literally nothing about TeX, but when trying to figure out how to split english words into syllables I saw that the TeX typesetting system has a syllable breaking algorithm. Is there a simple way that I could use this to break a bunch of words into syllables, or would it require a sizable ascent up the TeX learning curve?

Comment: @Mico Your comment looks very useful. Why not convert it to an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TeX has long featured a very sophisticated algorithm for *hyphenating* words. However, in English -- and, for that matter, all other Western languages I'm familiar with --*syllable boundaries* and permissible *hyphenation points* don't always coincide. Some further caveats:

- As Barbara Beeton has already pointed out in a comment on David Carlisle's answer, hyphenation may be deliberately disabled by TeX for certain multi-syllable words whose pronunciation and hyphenation both depend on the words' intended *meaning*. E.g., the word "record" is pronounced differently and would be hyphenated differently (rec-ord vs re-cord) depending on whether it's used as a noun or a verb. TeX is thus set *not* to hyphenate words such a record and records. If an author really needs to hyphenate such words, he/she has to insert a "discretionary" hyphenation point, `\-`, manually.
- By default, TeX's English-language related hyphenation rules won't hyphenate four-letter/two-syllable words (such as `onto`, `into`, and `upto`), and words ending in "ly" (as in `gladly`, `smoothly`, etc) won't see the final two-letter syllable hyphenated either. To work around this default setting, you could set `\righthyphenmin2` (or, if you use `babel`, issue the command `\renewcommand\englishhyphenmins{22}`). This isn't a panacea, though, as TeX's hyphenation rules aren't reliable when one deviates from `\righthyphenmin3`.

If you're content with using hyphenation points as an imperfect proxy for syllable boundaries, I would recommend you load the [showhyphens](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/showhyphens) package -- which requires use of Lua(La)TeX -- along with the [babel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package. With such a setup, all recognized hyphenation points in the document will be shown with little red marks.

For example, typesetting the text of your posting with this setup (see code below) produces the following output:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex % be sure to run this under LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[USenglish]{article} % choose whatever "version" of English that suits your needs
\usepackage{babel,showhyphens}
\renewcommand\USenglishhyphenmins{22} 
\begin{document}
I know literally nothing about \TeX, but when trying to figure out how to split 
english words into syllables I saw that the \TeX\ typesetting system has a syllable 
breaking algorithm. Is there a simple way that I could use this to break a bunch of 
words into syllables, or would it require a sizable ascent up the \TeX\ learning 
curve?
\end{document}
```

Comment: You pointed it out above, but to give a concrete example from the example paragraph.  "Sizable" has only one hyphenation point, `siz-able`, yet (for me at least) has 3 syllables: `siz-a-ble`.

Comment: @ScottH. - I fully agree. Another "interesting" word in the example paragraph is "english" -- I'm pretty sure that a lot of (most?) people would set the syllable boundary at eng-lish (phonetic representation: iŋ-lish), yet hyphenation occurs -- at least according to Merriam-Webster -- at en-glish.

Answer (score 18):

It depends what you mean by syllable, and what you want to do with the information

```
\showhyphens{syllable breaking algorithm}
```

Produces

```
syl-la-ble break-ing al-go-rithm
```

on the log (and it's possible to get that information within TeX to a certain extent) but whether "hyphenation point" corresponds to "syllable" depends a bit on whether you are using some specific technical definition of those terms. "Syllable" is usually strongly related to pronunciation, whereas hyphenation points depend on other factors as well, especially for example the UKenglish hyphenation patterns differ from the default US ones partly as they take more note of the etymology of the word even if that suggests different breaks than suggested by modern pronunciation (or at least that is one rationalisation of the differences).

Comment: I didn't know that.  Fascinating.

Comment: We actually don't know where the syllable boundaries are. Speakers differ in their intuitions. The boundaries might be decided upon on the fly when speakers are given the task of breaking up a word, and it's not clear that such boundaries (or syllables themselves) exist in the language beyond that.

Comment: there are also situations where two words spelled the same but having different functions (e.g., one is a verb and the other a noun) have different syllabification/pronunciation, and thus hyphenation, e.g., pro-ject vs. proj-ect.  since tex can't tell the difference, it avoids hyphenating such words, so there is no help to be had.